# How to fix '/bin/sh: 1: mysql: not found' in cloud function

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have cloud function that restores mysql dump into cloud mysql db. When the function is executed, i get an error

> /bin/sh: 1: mysql: not found

my `requirements.txt` has

```
google-cloud-storage
mysql-client
```

my main.py is as follows

```
import functions_framework
from google.cloud import storage
import os
import datetime
import subprocess

CURRENT_DATE = datetime.datetime.today().date()

# Triggered by a change in a storage bucket
@functions_framework.cloud_event
def restore_database(cloud_event):
    """Triggered by a change to a GCS bucket subfolder.
    It unzips the zipped sql dump file and restores it into cloud mysql using mysql command.

    Args:
        data (dict): The Cloud Functions event payload.
        context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata of triggering event.
    """
    data = cloud_event.data
    # Get the GCS bucket and file information from the event data
    bucket_name = data["bucket"]
    file_name = f'dumps/xxxx-{CURRENT_DATE}.sql.gz'

    # Only process .gz files in a subfolder named 'dumps'
    if not file_name.endswith('.gz') or 'dumps/' not in file_name:
        return

    # Initialize GCS client
    storage_client = storage.Client()

    # Get the bucket and blob objects
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(file_name)

    # Download the file to a temporary location
    tmp_file_name = '/tmp/' + os.path.basename(file_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(tmp_file_name)

    # Get database credentials from environment variables
    db_host = os.environ["SQL_INSTANCE_NAME"] 
    db_name = os.environ["DATABASE_NAME"]
    db_pass = os.environ["DATABASE_PASSWORD"]
    db_port = os.environ["DATABASE_PORT"]
    db_user = os.environ["DATABASE_USER"]

    # Unzip the file
    cmd = f"gzip -dk {tmp_file_name}"
    subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)

    # Get the name of the unzipped file
    unzipped_file_name = os.path.splitext(tmp_file_name)[0]

    # Run the mysql command to restore the database from the unzipped dump file
    cmd = f"mysql -u {db_user} -h {db_host} -P {db_port} -p'{db_pass}' {db_name} < {unzipped_file_name}"
    subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)

    # Delete the temporary files
    os.remove(tmp_file_name)
    os.remove(unzipped_file_name)

    print(f"Database {db_name} restored successfully from {file_name} in {bucket_name}")
```

How can I fix this issue? I've tries adding `mysql-server` or `mysql` in the `requirements.txt` but doesn't solve the problem.

I believe `mysql-client` doesn't install the mysql that's needed to run in the terminal using subprocess.

Comment: Try to installmysql-client package using the apt-get package manager in the Dockerfile or you can try using a pre-built Docker image that already has mysql-client installed.

Comment: @panther93 Cloud Function dos not use a Dockerfile so what you mention is not feasible.

Comment: Cloud Functions does not contain the MySQL `binary` and adding packages to the `requirements.txt` will not fix this. Instead use the `PyMySQL` package https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL and connect to the database directly instead of using the MySQL CLI. PD. There is no such thing as terminal in CF. Check the CF docs to understand how CF works https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/overview